# Armadillo compute the eigenvectors related to non null eigenvalues

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, armadillo, eigenvector

I need to compute the eigenvectors Corresponding to the N Smallest non null eigenvalues ​​of a symmetric  sparse matrix positive semi- definite.

I use the function `eigs_sym` from armadillo but it takes way longer to compute the eigenvectors corresponding to the smallest eigenvalues than to compute the eigenvector corresponding to the biggest eigenvalues.

Is it possible that the eigenvector corresponding to (almost) null eigenvalues are more difficult to compute ?

Since I'm not interested in the eigenvectors corresponding to the (almost) null eigenvalues, is there a way to indicate to armadillo to not compute thoses ?

Thank you by advance

Comment: So you can use `eigs_sym` to start at the smallest eigenvector by passing it the argument "sm", but I think you know that? Your problem is that you waste time calculating the null (to within rounding error) values when you want to calculate the non-null ones? I suspect you can't do that. You can also pass a tolerance to eigs_sym which might speed it up somewhat if you made that higher. (at the cost of lower precision)

Comment: Yes I currently use `eigs_sym` with the argument "sa" (equivalent to "sm" since the matrix is positive-definite). I wonder, since armadillo uses LAPACK, can't I use armadillo to compute eigenvalues and a low-level LAPACK procedure to compute the corresponding eigenvectors ?

Comment: `pdstein` in scaLAPACK (or a slight renaming for a different data type) might be worth a look. I honestly don't know how quick it will be. (http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/d1/da3/pdstein_8f_source.html) I'm also not sure if it works with a sparse matrix, or if there's a usable equivalent that does. I'm afraid that's the end of what I know on this, so I won't reply further!

Comment: (Actually that's only for tridiagonal matricies anyway)